# Effective c++ item 3 example

Tags: c++, effective-c++

My question is about a specific item (3) of the book "Effective C++".  The book gives this example that I tried to reproduce as close as possible into vs 2010 c++ (including iostream and string):

```
class TextBlock {
public: 
    const char& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
    {
        return text[pos]; 
    }
    char& operator[](std::size_t pos)
    { 
        return text[pos]; 
    }

private: 
    std::string text;
};

void print(const TextBlock& ctb)
{
    std::cout << ctb[0]; // OK
    //ctb[0] = ‘A’; // Not OK – compiler error
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TextBlock tb(“Hello”);
    std::cout << tb[0];
    tb[0] = ‘x’; // OK because return has &, not const
    const TextBlock ctb("World");
    std::cout << ctb[0];
    return 0;
}
```

And I get these compiling errors:

```
1>c:\users\lalancelot\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\item3\item3.cpp(31): error C2065: '“Hello”' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\lalancelot\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\item3\item3.cpp(33): error C2065: '‘x’' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\lalancelot\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\item3\item3.cpp(34): error C2664: 'TextBlock::TextBlock(const TextBlock &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'const TextBlock &'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'const TextBlock'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Let me first say that I am discouraged to already be stuck at this early stage of the book.  I have somehow found informations here:
   [difference between static_cast<const A>(*this) and static_cast<const A&>(*this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802556/difference-between-static-castconst-athis-and-static-castconst-athis),
but not a working answer like the one in the book.  I would like to make the book example work so I can understand how it works.  I've been stuck on this one for many days now and I must admit that I need help.  I would like to know if I am missing a base concept here or if I am way over my head.  Thanks.

Comment: Re: your first 2 errors; your quotes are wonky, they should be regular "typewriter double quotes" `"` but seem not to be.

Comment: It is quite clear that this code in the book is not complete, there are '...' parts in the class definition. The author of Effective C++ mentions that this should preferably be the second book read while learning C++. If you are just starting with the language it'll be probably better to find a different book and return to Effective C++ later

Comment: It is not my first book on c++ Jan, but I have not coded much c++.  I used to work in python and I want to go deeper.  I would like to say that I am ready for it, but to tell you the true, I have no idea if I am.  Thanks for the quote warning Joachim.

Answer (score 6):

What kind of quotes are you using?  I ask because when I look at your
code, I see distinct opening and closing quotes, and when I copy/paste
it into my editor, it indicates that they are Unicode opening and
closing quotes.  **All** punctuation in a C++ program should be pure
ASCII: 0x22 for the double quotes (both opening and closing), and 0x27
for the single quotes.  This is also what the corresponding characters
on the keyboard should give you when entering text *in a program
editor*.  (Do not use a word processor for entering code.)

Comment: Thank you, it is my French keyboard that cause this.  I'll now be in the look out for those.

Comment: @PierreLalancette Trying to write C++ with a French keyboard is a pain.  I'd suggest you load a US keyboard driver, and activate it when editing programs. (Windows is very good at this.  I've got my machine set up so that ALT-1 gives me US, ALT-2 French, ALT-3 German and ALT-0 whatever is engraved on the key caps.  I've done the same under Solaris in the past.)

Comment: Don't worry, I have the alt-shift switch between english and french.  It is just that I was not aware of the problem it could cause.  I'm used to program in english, I just have to be even more carefull about it.

Comment: @PierreLalancette I'm still surprised that the problem should be in the keyboard, and not the editor.  The French keyboards I've used do send 0x22 when I enter an unshifted 3.  Some text processors, however (including MS-Word, in certain configurations) will work out whether this character is an opening or closing quote, and change it, even in English.  When dealing with text, opening and closing quotes are different characters.

Comment: I have configured to switch language AND keybord with alt-shift.  It is really a question of accomoding (canadian) french writing with all proper position of keys.  I have tried many configurations, and this is the one that fits the configuration we are used to, and most people use around here.  It is not really a problem, since I am (and always should be) programming with the english keyboard and language.

Answer (score 2):

The class TextBlock needs a constructor to be constructable from a text:

```
explicit TextBlock( const std::string& s ) : text( s )
{
}
```

Maybe there is a website to the book where you can look up corrections to the book.

Comment: Yes!  This is the part I was missing.  For some reason, I though that the creation of the string was part of the operator [] overide.  I was so wrong.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, and I had looked into the book's errata.  They only talk about the fact that the 'pos' value should be a const.  Nothing else.