# In Effective C++ Item 3,why use static_cast<const TextBlock&>(*this) instead of static_cast<const TextBlock>(*this)?

Tags: c++, reference, effective-c++

I'm reading Scott Meyers's Effective C++ 3rd.
In item 3:

> Use const whenever possible. In order to use const member function operator[],non-const member function operator[] has to do 2 cast operations:
>
> ```
> const_cast<char&>(
>   static_cast<const TextBlock&>(*this)
>          [position]
> )
> ```

Why does Scott Meyers use `static_cast<const TextBlock&>(*this)` instead of `static_cast<const TextBlock>(*this)`?

Comment: … because that would copy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between static\_cast<const A>(\*this) and static\_cast<const A&>(\*this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802556/difference-between-static-castconst-athis-and-static-castconst-athis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static_cast<const TextBlock>(*this)` will create a temporary object, which is copied from `*this`. And then `operator[]` will be invoked on it, and the returned `char&` will be dangled when go out of the non-const member function `operator[]`. Note that dereference on it leads to UB.